# tkinter doesn't open image via function

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-menu

Tkinter doesn't open the image. We can ask the opening incorrectly, we need help. I need it to open the image through the menu. be sure to use pil, as the image can be anything. There are no errors in the syntax. Thank you = )

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Menu, Canvas, PhotoImage
import easygui
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter, ImageTk

def input_file():
    a = easygui.fileopenbox(filetypes=["*.jpg"])
    original = Image.open(a)
    original = original.resize((799, 799), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    photoimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(original)
    canvas = Canvas(root, width=799, height=799)
    imagesprite = canvas.create_image(10, 10,anchor='nw', image=photoimg)
    canvas.pack()
    return (imagesprite)

root = Tk()
root.title("Sputnikeca")
#root.iconbitmap('путь к иконке')
root.geometry("800x800+0+0")

my_menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=my_menu)

# Create a menu item

file_menu = Menu(my_menu)
my_menu.add_cascade(label = "Файл", menu=file_menu)
file_menu.add_command(label = "Импорт...", command=input_file())
file_menu.add_separator()
file_menu.add_command(label = "Выход", command=root.quit)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter command for button not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45710162/tkinter-command-for-button-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you have to do to solve the issue:

```
def input_file():
    global photoimg #keeping a reference
    a = easygui.fileopenbox(filetypes=["*.jpg"])
    original = Image.open(a).resize((799, 799), Image.ANTIALIAS) #calling it all in one line
    photoimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(original)
    canvas = Canvas(root, width=799, height=799)
    imagesprite = canvas.create_image(10, 10,anchor='nw', image=photoimg)
    canvas.pack()
    return imagesprite
```

and then later remove the `()` around your function:

```
file_menu.add_command(label = "Импорт...", command=input_file)
```

**What is being done?**

- In the first set of code im keeping a reference to the image so the image is not garbage collected by python. You can do so either by saying `imagesprite.image = photoimg` or `global photoimg` on top of the function. I also resized the image in the same line that I opened the image, to reduce codes.
- And in the second set of codes, im just removing `()` so that the function is not called(invoked) before choosing the menu item.
- And also tkinter itself has a `filedialogbox` that works like your `easygui.fileopenbox(filetypes=["*.jpg"])`, read some docs [here](https://pythonspot.com/tk-file-dialogs/)

  ```
  from tkinter import filedialog

  a = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='Choose a file',initialdir='C:/',filetypes=(('All Files','*.*'),("JPEG 
  Files",'*.jpeg')))
  ```

Hope this helped you solve the error, do let me know if any doubts.

Cheers

Comment: File "canvas.py", line 11, in input_file
    imagesprite.image = photoimg #keeping a reference
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'image'

There is a new error after 3 points! Thanks for the help from a student from the Russian Federation

Comment: @АртёмМакаренко Coupl you post the entire error code and update your Q with it along with the entire code youve tried

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, your menu opens as soon as you run the application, not when you click the import button.

It's because you need to pass the callback to the add_command, but you're calling the method instead

```
file_menu.add_command(label = "Import...", command=input_file())
```

Remove the () from input_file(). just pass input_file. it will not call the method directly anymore.

```
file_menu.add_command(label = "Import...", command=input_file)
```

Comment: This wont solve the problem of image not appearing, i guess

Comment: @CoolCloud That's why I added *If I am not mistaken*, as the question is not much clear, and it looks like OP is not comfortable with English, ' I need it to open the image through the menu. ' is what I thought was the the problem.